# Error While installing Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I have used [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm) procedure.I m using Linux Mint.

I am getting the following error while installing.

```
E: Unable to locate package libreadline6-dev
E: Unable to locate package libyaml-dev
E: Unable to locate package libgdbm-dev
E: Package 'ncurses-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'bison' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'subversion' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libffi-dev' has no installation candidate
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you didn't installed the `rvm requirements` .
Install the requirements like `libreadline6-dev` , `libyaml-dev` ,  `libgdbm-dev` ,etc..
I think This will solve the Problem.

Install all these with the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev \
curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison  \
subversion pkg-config
```

Or, Just refer [this](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) link.

Comment: HI ,
While installing RVM requirements i m getting following error

Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install libreadline6-dev libyaml-dev sqlite3 libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev bison libffi-dev'

I have tried using above command as you mentioned but still getting the same error.

Comment: I am also experiencing this error. Have those libraries you listed do not have installation candidates.

Answer (score 4):

This instructions are old, following [rvm installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install):

```
\curl -#L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=4 --ruby
```

It will:

1. Download and install RVM
2. Enable automatic requirements installation
3. Install ruby including all required dependencies

Comment: Why does the rvm main site refer to --autolibs=3 and in your link above you have --autolibs=4?

Comment: I was surprised to, but we will change the default to `4` shortly so there will be only an extra note about setting lower values in rare cases.

Comment: This solution is the quickest. It installs all the required dependencies for rvm and ruby in one command. I tried stable without the additional flags and it raised all kinds of unable to locate packages on ubuntu, which would have had me edit /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: Error running 'requirements_debian_libs_install g++ libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 autoconf libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev',
showing last 15 lines of /home/jeffrey/.rvm/log/1389233157_ruby-2.1.0/package_install_g++_libreadline6-dev_zlib1g-dev_libssl-dev_libyaml-dev_libsqlite3-dev_sqlite3_autoconf_libgdbm-dev_libncurses5-dev_automake_libtool_bison_libffi-dev.log
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Answer (score 0):

which OS you  using ?
if you using Ubuntu, 
then use the link :
http://blog.sudobits.com/2012/05/02/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts/

if you are using windows
 then problem while installing in some gem dependence like. 'libffi-dev',  less-rail

than used other OS that very well for "Ruby on Rails" like Linux/Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ubuntu, the copy and paste https://github.com/vaneyckt/Ruby-on-Rails-installation-script/blob/master/install.sh. You might need to hit enter at some point.

Comment: He indicated that on April 13th. My post was made on April 9th.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me.

WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!

```
    apt-get clean            # Remove cached packages
    cd /var/lib/apt 
    mv lists lists.old       # Backup mirror info
    mkdir -p lists/partial   # Recreate directory structure
    apt-get clean
    apt-get update           # Fetch mirror info
```